# Removing HTML tags from a unicode string in Python

Tags: python, html, string, unicode, replace

I have a strong that I scraped from an XML file and It contains some HTML formatting tags

```
(<b>, <i>, etc)
```

Is there a quick and easy way to remove all of these tags from the text?

I tried

```
str = str.replace("<b>","")
```

and applied it several times to other tags, but that doesn't work

Comment: Please don't use `str` as a variable name.

Comment: Mark, I'm not, I just typed that for the example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using lxml.html:

```
lxml.html.fromstring(s).text_content()
```

This strips all tags and converts all entities to their corresponding characters.

Comment: Thanks! I get 

    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'html' 

when I try this though

Answer (score 1):

Answer depends on your exact needs. You might have a look at regular expressions. But I would advise you to use http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/ if you want to clean up bad xml or html.

Comment: Doesn't sound like he wants to parse any html, just strip it all away so he is left with plain text (kind of like the innerHTML function).

Comment: Stephen, you're correct.

I'm not trying to parse the string, I just want to remove the HTML formatting (anything inside a <> I want removed completely)

Comment: Oops, I meant the innerText property, not the "innerHTML function"

Comment: You will not be able to "just" remove the HTML formatting without more sophisticated parsing. Might be possible for some simple samples, but not for complex ones.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to use the [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) module to replace only some tags, leaving the rest of the HTML alone:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

def strip_tags(html, invalid_tags):
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
  for tag in soup.findAll(True):
    if tag.name in invalid_tags:
      s = ""
      for c in tag.contents:
        if type(c) != NavigableString:
          c = strip_tags(unicode(c), invalid_tags)
        s += unicode(c)
      tag.replaceWith(s)
  return soup

html = "<p>Good, <b>bad</b>, and <i>ug<b>l</b><u>y</u></i></p>"
invalid_tags = ['b', 'i', 'u']
print strip_tags(html, invalid_tags)
```

Result:

```
<p>Good, bad, and ugly</p>
```