# Python html processing

Tags: python, text-processing, nltk

I have a html file with russian text. How i can get all words in text without html tags, special symbols, etc ?

Example:

```
<html>...<body>...<div id='text'>Foo bar! Foo, bar.</div></body></html>
```

I need:

```
['foo','bar','Foo','bar']
```

I tried nltk, but it does not support russian words.

Comment: Don't know russian. Maybe you can try BeautifulSoup.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing HTML tags from a unicode string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224358/removing-html-tags-from-a-unicode-string-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

Definitely try [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), it [supports Unicode](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit).

Comment: While I support this answer (+1), I feel that I should warn that BeautifulSoup is basically deprecated. I've used it before and love it, but there isn't as much official support for it anymore

Comment: Not true -- as of yesterday, BeautifulSoup 4 is out in beta.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using [lxml](http://lxml.de/) library to parse xml/html. lxml works good with any unicode data.

Comment: `lxml.html.fromstring(s).text_content()` But OP wants to spit text to words too.

Comment: It would be a second stage of html processing. Split words is simple task generally but could be very language specific. So I prefer to split words in the second stage of html parsing.

Comment: Could you provide me some example of the html you need to parse?

Answer (score 0):

Use `lxml`. It can strip tags, elements, and more:

```
import urllib2

from lxml import etree


URL = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230675/python-html-processing'

html = urllib2.urlopen(URL).read()
tree = etree.fromstring(html, parser=etree.HTMLParser())

tree.xpath('//script')
# [<Element script at 102f831b0>,
#  ...
#  <Element script at 102f83ba8>]

tree.xpath('//style')
# [<Element style at 102f83c58>]

tags_to_strip = ['script', 'style']
etree.strip_elements(tree, *tags_to_strip)

tree.xpath('//style')
# []

tree.xpath('//script')
# []

body = tree.xpath('//body')
body = body[0]

text = ' '.join(body.itertext())
tokens = text.split()
# [u'Stack',
#  u'Exchange',
#  u'log',
#  u'in',
#  ...
#  u'Stack',
#  u'Overflow',
#  u'works',
#  u'best',
#  u'with',
#  u'JavaScript',
#  u'enabled']
```

In case of text in russian you get tokens looking likes this:

```
# [u'\xd1\x8d\xd1\x84\xd1\x84\xd0\xb5\xd0\xba\xd1\x82\xd1\x8b\xe2\x80\xa6',
#  u'\xd0\x9c\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xba',
#  ...
#  u'\xd0\x9c\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80']
```

Errors handling is your home assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to remove the tags. Nltk is all about language analysis (nouns vs verbs) and word meaning (semantics) not string removal and pattern matching although I can see how someoneaybe confused.

Here is a removal function using regex

```
import re
def remove_html_tags(data):
    p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
    return p.sub('', data)
```